# getting selected value for select list in angular from a $firebaseArray()

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have a simple select list that is based on a $firebaseArray(). I dont have a problem getting the values into the drop. Just the selected value.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selectedRole"
                             ng-options="role.name for role in vm.allRoles">
</select>
```

The $firebaseArray looks like this

[image]

In my controller the function that initializes the form with the select is

```
 Get.getParentUrl('roles').$loaded()
    .then(function (data) {
          vm.allRoles = Get.getParentUrl('roles');
          vm.selectedRole = entity.role.name;
    })
```

And this populates the select but it does not set the selected value for it on `vm.selectedRole`. Note that `entity` is the value that is being passed , so if i write a

```
console.log(entity.role.name);
```

The returned value is the selected value that is being passed. So if the user selects a user with a role **"Supervisor"** and i write a `console.log(vm.selectedRole)` inside the `.then(function(data){` the value returned is **"Supervisor"**

However the html displays a **"?"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding the vm.selectedRole like so

```
vm.selectedRole =  { name: entity.role.name };
```

Which works i guess. Syntax seems a bit crappy though

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Not sure what's crappy about this. A bit unclear from your answer. You can also access the record ID by using `role.$key`, since your names probably require you to convert those back to keys anyway.

Comment: Because its JSON. If i want to use the selecedRole.$id i get a " cannot pass json" error. I will try accessing from the $key though. thanks